# How to save the image for a Custom Button with User Defaults in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

What I want to do is that the app starts with a custom button that has a simple image as a background. If the user taps on the "enter" button, the image of the custom button will permanently change, and if the user restarts the app, the second image will still appear instead of the first one. [image: This is the image when the user starts the app for the first time.]
[image: This is the image that the user will see as he/she taps the enter button, and that image is saved permanently.]

Answer (score 1):

When the button clicked, save a flag value in UserDefaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("1", forKey: "kIsButtonSelected")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

When relaunch the app, check the value and set the image for button:

```
if let isButtonSelected = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "kIsButtonSelected") as? String {
    if isButtonSelected == "1" {
        //set the second image
    }
}
```

And a **better practice** is to set first image for button's normal status, and second one for selected status. And just set the button's status when the flag value is detected:

```
button.isSelected = true  //the image will be changed to the second one automatically.
```

Comment: this isn't a bad approach, but it may be better to just store the image name as the key... then, when loading the button image just match the value from UD to a list of images. This allows much more flexibility I think, such as custom avatars etc (which is where I think the OP is going with this)

Comment: Yes, I just provide the simple solution for Francisco to understand quickly. And I added a better practice to the answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, so that way you can use more than 1 picture if desired:

```
// Put a all of your images that you want here:
var imageDictionary = ["smilyface": UIImage(named: "smilyface.png"),
                       "person"   : UIImage(named: "person.png"),
                       // and so on...
]

// Use this whenever you want to change the image of your button:
func setCorrectImageForButton(imageName name: String) {
  UserDefaults.standard.set(name, forKey: "BUTTONIMAGE")
}

// Then use this to load the image to your button:
// myButtonImage = grabCorrectImageForButton() 
func grabCorrectImageForButton() -> UIImage? {

  guard let imageKey = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "BUTTONIMAGE") else {
    print("key not found!")
    return nil
  }

  if let foundImage = imageDictionary[imageKey] {
    return foundImage
  }
  else {
    print("image not found!")
    return nil
  }
}
```